# Getting a type Surface error with argument 1. How would I fix it?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Python 1.9.6. I have a `class` which is the main one for the subclass's. I'm experiencing an error: the line with the error --> `window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y)) TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None`.

Code:

```
class Ship:
def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.health = health
    self.ship_img = None
    self.laser_img = None
    self.lasers = []
    self.cool_down_counter = 0

def draw(self, window):
    window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))

def get_width(self):
    return self.ship_img.get_width()

def get_height(self):
    return self.ship_img.get_height()
```

The reason it has to be `None` because it has several images of the same class(meaning using the same variables) but with different coordinates and properties. It can't be a list, because then the `.get_width()` and `.get_height()` won't work. I'm using those to create barriers for the image(s).
I'm following along with the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-__8Xw9KTM&ab_channel=TechWithTim. I'm at around 51:41 of the video. Thank you for the advice as always.

Comment: *"The reason it has to be `None` [...]"* - no it must not be `None`. You have to set the attribute `self.ship_img` by a `pygame.Surface`. I'm sure that is done somewhere in the tutorial and you missed it.

Comment: False it stayed None the entire time. It always worked at the end so it resolved itself as it seems.

Comment: If it stays `None` the the code will not work. The error is caused by the fact that the value of the attribute is `None`. You still missed something. *"it resolved itself as it seems [...]"* - No it does not. Either the attribute is set outside the class or the class is a base class of another class. But if you insist I'm wrong, then maybe the tutorial was written by a wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Just test that  `self.ship_img` is not `None`, before drawing the object:

```py
class Ship:
    # [...]
    
    def draw(self, window):
        if self.ship_img != None:
            window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))
```